# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{*} \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x],+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Q}^{*}$ be the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{*}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}[x],+)$.

My intuition is telling me that this is not true, but this is what my book is asking me to prove. I have tried to think of a isomorphic mapping for a while now and the best I can do is a homomorphism namely, 
$$\phi(a_0+a_1x+ \cdots a_nx^n)=\frac{a_0}{a_n}$$
If anyone could verify that these really aren't isomorphic or give me a hint on how to get started that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: From the hint in the comments I have come up with this,  Let $a=p_1^{a_0}p_2^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ and $b=p_1^{b_0} p_2^{b_1} \cdots p_n^{b_n}$ so that $\frac{a}{b}=p_1^{a_0-b_0} \cdots p_n^{a_n-b_n}$ and then considering the mapping 
$$\phi(\frac{a}{b})=(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)x+ \cdots (a_n-b_n)x^n$$ then verifing that this is an isomorphism. Would this be correct?

Comment: Hint: Consider enumerating the primes and then consider prime factorizations of numerator and denominator (note that you correctly ask about positive rationals but the notation means all nonzero rationals).

Comment: We have $$\Bbb Q_{>0} \cong \bigoplus_{p \text{ prime }} \Bbb Z \cong (\Bbb Z[x], +).$$

Comment: Your attempt in the edit is spot on.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: $-1\in Q^*$ is an element of order 2